# No output during word swap

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>   /* for access to the toupper function */

void reverse_name(char *name);


int main(void)
{
    char input[100];

    printf("Enter a first and last name: ");
    gets(input);
    reverse_name(input);
    return 0;
}

void reverse_name(char *name){
    char *first = name;
    char *see;
    see = name;
    while(*see != ' '){
    }
    while(*see != '\n'){
        putchar(*see);
    }
    printf(", %c",*first);
}
```

I want this to happen: Enter a first and last name: Lloyd Fosdick

And the output be like this: Fosdick, L.

But after entering a first and last name, Lloyd Fosdick, the program doesn't give any answer and nothing happens? Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: while(*see != ' '){
} this is your first problem..

the second while is your second problem..

Comment: What Alon said: The condition in the `while` loop will never change. If the first character isn't a space, you get an infinite loop. You could do `while (*see != ' ') see++;`, but you might read beyond the end of the string if it doesn't contain a space.

Comment: Was there really no more descriptive title that came to your mind than _"Whats wrong with my code"_ ?

Comment: Thanks it helped I tries to ask a better question next time sorry.

Comment: To WhozCraig C Programming a modern approach

Answer (score 2):

You neither increment `see` nor check for `0` terminator in both of your while loops:

```
while(*see && *see != ' '){
   see++;
}

while(*see && *see != '\n'){
   putchar(*see);
   see++;
}
```

`gets()` has been removed from C11 and you should never use it even if you are following older standards. Use `fgets()` instead.

This is by no means a complete fix. You'll have to ask yourself:

- what if the input contains more than one space between the names?
- what if the input contains more than two names?
- What if there's *no* first name or last name?
- etc.

You need to think about all these cases and handle them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop

```
while(*see != ' '){}
```

You need to increment your pointer position.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is better code

(**gets function is deprecated**)

You read format code. their is space between firstName and secondName.

No infinite loops not loops at all.

```
int main(void)
{
    char firstName[100];
    char secName[100];
    printf("Enter a first and last name: ");
    scanf("%s %s",firstName,secName);
    printf("%s ,%c",secName,firstName[0]);
    return 0;
}
```